# Access Webpack bundle parts from Requirejs

Tags: webpack, requirejs

I have a currently RequireJS application that we're transforming into Webpack. However, parts of the application are and will be dynamically loaded, which means that they're cannot of course be part of the Webpack bundle. This is fine, we'll just use RequireJS for those.

However, those dynamically loaded parts may refer back to parts of the static application. This would, of course, cause RequireJS to load the original, pre-bundle code and instantiate it, causing the code to duplicate and eg. event messaging bus to not be shared between the Webpack and RequireJS world.

Now the question is; would it be possible to somehow configure Webpack to some known parts of the bundle and then configure RequireJS to load them from the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem.

The answer was to explicitly define those parts that I want RequireJS to access from Webpack bundle at the beginning of the program.

Essentially this would mean that in the RequireJS config I would change

`paths: { "utils" : "frontend-modules/utils" }`

with

`import errorUtils from "utils/error";
 window.define("utils/error", () => errorUtils);`

for every utility library within `utils` directory.

A very annoying solution, definitely, but removes to need to keep extra libs available for RequireJS and the need to fetch them.